# How to get all columns of model [entity framework]

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have model, for example:

```
class Users 
{
    public string Username {get; set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

I need get all variables of class `Users` (`Username` and `Password`) and set to `ViewBag`.

Like this:

```
var db = new DatabaseContext();
var AllVars = db.Users.GetAllVariables();

foreach(item in AllVars)
{
    ViewBag.item.NameVariable = item.NameVariable
}
```

This code of course doesn't work, but how to do like this?

Comment: If you want to send all proerpty values, why not to send whole user?

Comment: can you share this method's code `GetAllVariables()`?

Comment: @Sampath GetAllVariable is for example :)

Comment: Do you need all variables, declared  like `var a= db.Users;` `var b= db.Users;` and then you need `a` and `b` ??

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection to get public properties:

```
var AllVars = db.Users.GetType().GetProperties(
  System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

foreach(var item in AllVars)
{
  ViewBag.item.NameVariable = item.Name;
}
```

Comment: @Helperus In this case try to play with the binding flags.

Comment: Are your properties declared public?

Comment: Yes above my class Users i have code:

 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var path = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=" + Path.Combine(path, "database.db"));
        }

Comment: @Helperus I fixed the binding flags, should work now.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for help but the same. I write db.Users not Models.User - maybe it is?


If I do Models.User i have - an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property

Comment: With the latest fix, there is no need to specify the binding flags at all, because these are the defaults for the parameterless `GetProperties` method.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thx for the hint, didnt know that.

Comment: And of course `db.Users.GetType()` is a mistake. It should be either `typeof(Users)` or `db.Users.AsQueryable().ElementType`

Comment: @Helperus Then try `typeof(Users).GetProperties()`

Comment: @Helperus - Yes - Typeof it works! I have one more question, how now to get name in foreach?

I very wants give all of you pros, but i can not 

edit: Works, add .Name 

Thanks for help :)

Comment: @Helperus *how now to get name in foreach* - do not compute, what do you mean? The example above already retrieves the property name by `item.Name`